# Set mongoDB replica set version to a previous value

Tags: mongodb

I have a 3-replica MongoDB set with the following configuration:

```
rs0:PRIMARY> rs.conf()
{
    "_id" : "rs0",
    "version" : 138086,
    "members" : [
        {
            "_id" : 0,
            "host" : "host_1:27017",
            "arbiterOnly" : false,
            "buildIndexes" : true,
            "hidden" : false,
            "priority" : 1,
            "tags" : {

            },
            "slaveDelay" : 0,
            "votes" : 1
        },
        {
            "_id" : 1,
            "host" : "host_2:27017",
            "arbiterOnly" : false,
            "buildIndexes" : true,
            "hidden" : false,
            "priority" : 0.5,
            "tags" : {

            },
            "slaveDelay" : 0,
            "votes" : 1
        },
        {
            "_id" : 2,
            "host" : "host_3:27017",
            "arbiterOnly" : false,
            "buildIndexes" : true,
            "hidden" : false,
            "priority" : 0.5,
            "tags" : {

            },
            "slaveDelay" : 0,
            "votes" : 1
        }
    ],
    "settings" : {
        "chainingAllowed" : true,
        "heartbeatTimeoutSecs" : 10,
        "getLastErrorModes" : {

        },
        "getLastErrorDefaults" : {
            "w" : 1,
            "wtimeout" : 0
        }
    }
}
```

As you may have noticed, the version number is some garbage value. It was earlier 9, and then I changed something to make it 10. However, another instance connection to the DB needs it to have version 9. I tried:

```
cfg = rs.conf()
cfg.version = 9
rs.reconfig(cfg, { force: true } )
```

But that created the garbage value. Is there any way I can set it back to 9? Oh, and rs.initiate() didn't work either. This [link](http://www.tutespace.com/2016/03/stopping-and-starting-mongodb.html) describes how to do it by shutting down the replica set completely. That is too dangerous for me as it is in production.

Answer (score 0):

> It was earlier 9, and then I changed something to make it 10. However, another instance connection to the DB needs it to have version 9.

The replica set configuration [`version`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/replica-configuration/#rsconf.version) value is not meant to be changed manually. This value is an incrementing number used to distinguish configuration versions so a driver or replica set member knows their configuration is current.

> As you may have noticed, the version number is some garbage value.

This is an expected outcome of a [forced reconfiguration](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/reconfigure-replica-set-with-unavailable-members/):

> > When you use force : true, the version number in the replica set configuration increases significantly, by tens or hundreds of thousands. This is normal and designed to prevent set version collisions if you accidentally force re-configurations on both sides of a network partition and then the network partitioning ends.

Forced reconfiguration should only be used for disaster recovery and is not intended for normal reconfiguration:

> > The `force` option forces a new configuration onto the member. Use this procedure only to recover from catastrophic interruptions. Do not use `force` every time you reconfigure. Also, do not use the `force` option in any automatic scripts and do not use `force` when there is still a primary.

.

> Is there any way I can set it back to 9?

There should be no normal operational reason to change the version back to 9, and doing so may create unexpected problems with your deployment (for example, potential rollback of committed writes). You could go to some effort to change this with downtime but I would recommend leaving this as is (particularly for a production environment).

> Oh, and rs.initiate() didn't work either.

The `rs.initiate()` command is only used once in the lifecycle of a replica set: when you initialise the first member of the replica set in order to create an oplog.